# Windows 10 Docker Container Connection

Tags: docker

I am trying to run docker on windows 10, installation worked fine. Now I am running few containers like below.

```
 docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
7a86a28e4116        data-extractor_php-fpm   "/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.…"   About an hour ago   Up 29 minutes       9000/tcp               data-extractor-php-fpm
09105815a3c4        nginx:alpine             "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About an hour ago   Up 29 minutes       0.0.0.0:6000->80/tcp   data-extractor-webserver
```

The nginx container is running, But may I know, how to connect to this container from browser, 
normally on mac it works like below

```
http://localhost:6000/
```

May I know how to access this container in wondows 10?

Comment: The same way you do on Mac; through `localhost` on the corresponding port.

Comment: Well, but browser throws error, saying like not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, found the answer by myself. It appears to be chrome issue, chrome refusing to connect to port 6000 throwing error like unsafe port, either change settings in browser or update compose file to use allowed ports by chrome, and second step will be to update hosts file map docker machine ip to localhost. Docker ip can tracable by using following command.

```
ipconfig
```

hope it helps others.